# Proof that the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \max\{w_1^Tx, \ldots, w_N^Tx\} \geq \gamma\}$ is not convex in general

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ and $x$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\gamma$ be some constant in $\mathbb{R}$.

How can I prove that the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \max\{w_1^Tx, \ldots, w_N^Tx\} \geq \gamma\}$ is not convex in general?

(I'm asking for a proof and not for a counterexample.)

Thanks

Comment: "Prove that some property does not hold in general" is a problem that practically _begs_ for a counterexample. And a counterexample is ample proof. It is often the _only_ way to prove that there are cases where the property does not hold. That being said, if $\gamma > 0$, then $0$ won't be in your set. That's a good place to start looking for a counterexample.

Comment: I would like to get the counterexample by assuming a minimal amount of stuff about $w_1, \ldots, w_N$. The constant $gamma$ you can choose for yourself. While it is easy to see that the $\leq$ sign yields a convex set, the non convexity of this set does not seem immediate, even though it is easy to come up with counterexamples in particular cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposition.** Let $n\in \mathbb N$ be arbitray, $N\ge 2$, $w_1,\ldots, w_N\in\mathbb R^n$ arbitrary, $\gamma>0$.
Assume that there exist $1\le i<j\le N$ such that the only solution to 
$$\alpha w_i+\beta w_j=0\qquad\text{with }\alpha\ge0,\beta\le 0 $$
is the trivial solution $\alpha=\beta=0$. (For example, if $w_i,w_j$ are linearly independant).

Then the set 
$$ S = \{\,x\in\mathbb R^n:\max\{w_1^Tx,\ldots w_N^Tx\}\ge \gamma\,\}$$
is not convex.

*Proof:*
It suffices to show that $S\cap\langle w_i,w_j\rangle$ is not convex. In other words, it suffices to consider the cases

- $n=2$ and $w_i,w_j$ linearly independant
- $n=1$ and $ w_i\ne0$, $w_j=cw_i$ with $c<0$.

First case:
If $w_i={a\choose b}$ and $w_j={c\choose d}$, then we have $ad-bc\ne0$ from linear independence.
Let $v={b+d\choose -a-c}$. Then $$w_i^Tv=a(b+d)-b(a+c)=ad-bc$$
and
$$w_j^Tv=c(b+d)-d(a+c)=bc-ad.$$
Therefore the two points $$\pm\frac \gamma{ad-bc}v$$
are in $S$, but theri midpoint $0$ is not.

Second case: We have $\frac{\gamma}{w_i^Tw_i}w_i\in S$ and $\frac{\gamma}{cw_i^Tw_i}w_i\in S$, but the point $0$ between them is $\notin S$.
 $_\square$

---

*Remark:* If no $i,j$ as in the proposition exist, then either all $w_i$ are zero (making $S$ empty and hence convex if $\gamma>0$) or are nonnegative multiples of one nonzero vector (making $S$ a half-space and hence convex, even if $\gamma\le 0$).

Comment: Why the restriction on $\alpha$ and $\beta$? Couldn't they just belong to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If I replace "with $\alpha\ge 0,\beta\le 0$" with "with $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb R$", the condition just says "linearly independant". My restriction *additionally* (that's why I added "For example .. independant") catches cases where the vectors are dependant but point in opposite directions. And as the remark shows, this allowed me to "catch them all".

Answer (score 0):

You can see this as a set of inequalities
$$
w_ix \geq \gamma
$$
which defines a half-space (with boundary hyper-plane which is orthogonal to $w_i$). The way you put the inequalities together (with the $\max$-function) makes the resulting set the union of these half-spaces. Can you take it from there?